# Xero api - how to add custion fields in Bank Transactions posting api

Tags: xero-api

We need to include additional notes or text while using the bank transactions posting API (https://api.xero.com/api.xro/2.0/BankTransactions).

We would like to receive the same information in the response as well. We attempted to use the "Reference" field, but it does not appear in the response. Are there any other fields available for this purpose?